# Migrating Wordpress database to server SQL error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel, database-migration

I have just finished a Wordpress site and I'm trying to set it up on the server. I did the following, as always:

1. uploaded a .htaccess file to a public_html folder with the text from https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess (basic WP)
2. moved all the contents from the local wordpress folder to public_html
3. exported my local database and changed all instances of 'localhost/siteName/wordpress' with 'www.siteAddress.com'
4. created a mySQL database in cPanel's mySQL section
5. created a new user in cPanel's mySQL section
6. changed the wp_config file so that db_name, db_user and db_password values mach the prefix_name, prefix_username and user password of the newly created db/user
7. added that user to the database with all privileges granted
8. TRIED to import the exported local database to server via cPanel's phpMyadmin section. That's where I got this error:

   ## 1044 - Access denied for user 'something'@'localhost' to database 'else'

Of course, 'something' and 'else' are not the real values... Can anyone tell me if I did something wrong, or I didn't do something else at all? I never had this problem before? The differences are that the Wordpress itself got updated in the meantime and I worked with WooCommerce for the first time... if it matters, though I suspect it doesn't.

Thanks in advance, I know it's a bit of reading :)

[EDIT]: I tried the same procedure again (third time in a row), and it worked... so, the solution would be - the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this dzenesiz and see if this helps.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/mysql-1044-access-denied-error-message

Comment: I already went to that link, but it didn't solve the problem. I tried twice those steps I wrote above, and nothing. Then I took a brake, tried again and it worked like a charm (if you wondered)... I'm pretty confused, but not complaining :)

Comment: Cool Deal! Sometimes all you need is a little refresher. Have a nice day!